# Adding Coroutine functions to Transform

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, extension-methods

I'm creating a script in unity extending Transform

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;

public static class TransformExtension
{
    //lots of functions

     public static IEnumerator tester(this Transform test)
    {
        Debug.Log("hello");
        yield return null;
    }


    public static void tester2(this Transform test)
    {
        Debug.Log("hello2");
    } 
}
```

when I invoke

```c#
transform.tester();
transform.tester2();
```

only "hello2" is logged.

when I tried

```c#
StartCoroutine(transform.tester());
```

i got the following errors:

> "error CS0103: The name 'tester' does not exist in the current context"
>
> "Transform' does not contain a definition for 'StartCoroutine' and no accessible extension method 'StartCoroutine' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

when I tried

```c#
transform.StartCoroutine(transform.tester());
```

I got:

> "error CS1061: 'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'StartCoroutine' and no accessible extension method 'StartCoroutine' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: TransformExtension means it inherits `Transform`? or it's name is just "TransformExtension"?

Comment: @HeejaeKim [extension methods](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/extension-methods) are allways declared in a `public static class` which can not inherit from `Transform`

Answer (score 6):

1. You can not call a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) like a method you rather have to start it via [`StartCoroutine()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html). When you call it like a normal method it will simply be ignored (as you already noticed).
2. You can't use `transform.StartCoroutine()` since [`Transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) is of type [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) and does **not** inherit from [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html).

   But [`StartCoroutine()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) can only be used on a [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html).

---

So assuming you are already calling it from within a `MonoBehaviour` due to the usage of `transform` instead simply do

```c#
StartCoroutine(transform.tester());
```

which works completely fine for me as long as called from within a `MonoBehaviour` or alternatively

```c#
anyGameObject.GetComponent<MonoBehaviour>().StartCoroutine(transform.tester());
```

That other [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) which will be running the [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) doesn't even have to be on the same object but you have to be sure there is any other `MonoBehaviour` script attached to `anyGameObject`.

Comment: Additionally a `yield` at the end of a coroutine method does nothing. What's going to get put on hold? Nothing.

Comment: @Draco18s that's true but somewhere there **has** to be a `yield` in every `IEnumerator` .. in that case OP only wanted to test calling a Courinte in general so it's fine I guess (at least I don't know another workaround for that)

Comment: and what if he wants the `Debug.Log` in the same frame? ^^ It is just an example and I'm 99% sure OP won't even use it like that .. he just wanted to provide a minimal example .. and he did ;)

Comment: Sure, it compiles and runs, but it does nothing to confirm that it is running as a coroutine and that it is being paused and resumed at a later time. Plus it leads to writing bigger functions (with no other yields) with an unnecessary yield at the end because "otherwise the compiler complains." Or with other yields and the one at the end is left over from a test and was never removed because they don't know why it is there, only that "it needed to be there before..."

Comment: thank you all for the profound assistance and discussion.
as derHugo i only provided a minimal example since I don't think writing a huge block of code with everything I want to do will help with the specific question at hand.

for that I needed a simple example and had to put some yield somewhere.
change it to (wait for seconds) and print afterwards if you may, but the task was calling it, not how it runs

in this case i was writing an extension to Transform.
when i wanted to add coroutine functions like MoveTo, i encountered this error.

Comment: DerHugo
does it mean that i can put in a static script function that runs 
`anyGameObject.GetComponent<MonoBehaviour>().StartCoroutine(transform.tester());`
and use the monobehaviour of the script that calls it to activate the coroutine?

Comment: I don't understand the question sorry ... what I was trying to say is that any `MonoBehaviour` component can be used to start the coroutine via `StartCoroutine` it doesn't matter how and where you get that MonoBehaviour reference from. So if you are running a coroutine anyway simply using `StartCoroutine(transform.tester())` should be enough. As said `GetComponent<MonoBehaviour>()` works as long as there is any MonoBehaviour script attahced to `anyGameObject`

Answer (score 1):

You can not start coroutines like function calls Add a function which starts coroutine. Also since derHugo pointed out you need Monobehavior to achieve this you can access MonoBehavior over your transform like this:

```
public static IEnumerator Tester()
{
    Debug.Log("hello");
    yield return null;
}
public static void StartTester(this Transform test)
{
    test.GetComponent<MonoBehaviour>().StartCoroutine(Tester());
}

public static void tester2(this Transform test)
{
    Debug.Log("hello2");
}
```

Then do this:

```
transform.startTester();
```

Comment: This won't work since you can't use `StartCoroutine()` in a `static` context. It has to be called on a `MonoBehaviour` instance and `Transform` does not inherit from `MonoBehaviour`. (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54808433/7111561))

Comment: I tried to do somethingn like

    `public static void tester(this Transform test)
    {
        StartCoroutine(test.rectester(test));
    }
    static IEnumerator rectester(this Transform test)
    {
        Debug.Log("hello");

        bool isRect = test.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        yield return null;

    }`

but it seems like working as it says
error CS0103: The name 'StartCoroutine' does not exist in the current context

guess its because it is not part on monobehaviour so it must be in the user function

Comment: @user2956754 yes it wont work check out the answer above please

Comment: I edited answer and it works. It is a lot similar to what @derHugo did  i think but his approach is more generic and better probably.

Comment: It still will only work if there is a `MonoBehaviour` attached to that transform ;)

Comment: @derHugo Sorry i think i have a misunderstanding. I could not think of a scenario when there is `transform` without `MonoBehaviour`. Can you clarify that?

Comment: the thing is you made it really complicated where all that OP has to do is get rid of the first `transform.` in his call ;) you're approach would not work for a `Transform` component that doesn't have another `MonoBehaviour` script attached on the same GameObject since `Transform` itself isn't one. Sou you could use it still in another script calling `transform.startTester();` but it would fail if you do something like `Find(anyObjectWithOnlyTransform).transform.startTester()`

Comment: Ah you are right. It did not work. Thanks for clarification!